# Sorting a List of List in Python by frequency

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of list items in Python by the frequency of the occurrence 
The unsorted list looks something like this :

```
a=[     ['item1', 'item2', 'element2'],
        ['item3', 'item4', 'element3'],
        ['item5', 'item6', 'element1'],
        ['item7', 'item8', 'element3']]
```

I would like to sort by the frequency of the 3rd element of the list. So, the result list after sorting, would look something this :

```
result = [  ['item3', 'item4', 'element3'],
            ['item7', 'item8', 'element3'],
            ['item1', 'item2', 'element2'],
            ['item5', 'item6', 'element1']]
```

I am not an expert with Python. Any idea, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to collect frequencies first; a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) would do this nicely. You can then look up frequencies and order by that:

```
from collections import Counter

freq = Counter(item[-1] for item in a)
result = sorted(a, key=lambda i: freq[i[-1]], reverse=True)
```

Here `freq` holds counts for the last element in each nested list, which we then use a sort key, in reverse order (most frequent sorted first).

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a=[     ['item1', 'item2', 'element2'],
...         ['item3', 'item4', 'element3'],
...         ['item5', 'item6', 'element1'],
...         ['item7', 'item8', 'element3']]
>>> freq = Counter(item[-1] for item in a)
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda i: freq[i[-1]], reverse=True)
[['item3', 'item4', 'element3'], ['item7', 'item8', 'element3'], ['item1', 'item2', 'element2'], ['item5', 'item6', 'element1']]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
[['item3', 'item4', 'element3'],
 ['item7', 'item8', 'element3'],
 ['item1', 'item2', 'element2'],
 ['item5', 'item6', 'element1']]
```

Comment: can i achieve this using operator.itemgetter instead of lamba expression?

Comment: @iamdeowanshi no, this uses nested indexing and an `itemgetter()` instance can't achieve the same result here.

Comment: if we are going with normal nested list, itemgetter can be used then why not for sorting nested list with frequency

Comment: @iamdeowanshi: That's because the `itemgetter(value)` object is essentially the same as `lambda item: item[value]`. The lambda here is *different* from that.

Comment: @iamdeowanshi: `i[-1]` is the last element of the thing being sorted. `freq[...]` is a lookup in the `Counter()` mapping, so mapping an element to their frequency. So for each sorted `['itemN', 'itemO', 'itemP`]` list, the frequecy of `'itemP'` is looked up and returned to sort on.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Example:

```
wordlist = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz']
import collections
counter = collections.Counter(wordlist)
counter.most_common()
```

returns:

```
[('foo', 2), ('baz', 1), ('bar', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to import Counter or anything else, just define your own key function which will just return the last element of a list, so to make the sorting based on that element...

Hence, you could use 'sorted' with the key function last_element (that you defined) like this:

```
def last_element(x): return x[-1]

sorted(a, key=last_element, reverse=True)
```

and you get:

```
[['item3', 'item4', 'element3'], ['item7', 'item8', 'element3'], ['item1', 'item2', 'element2'], ['item5', 'item6', 'element1']]
```

If you don't want to define a new function you can use lambda (similar as shown in another answer), so the solution in just one line would be:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True)
```